# Can I query a different server in a SQL Server Agent job?

Tags: sql-server

When creating a T-SQL step in a SQL Server Agent job, is there a way to pull from a database on a different server?  For example, I'd like to query different database job histories across all of the various servers.  Possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides running queries via linked servers there is also the whole 'multiserver' concept in SQL Agent. See:

- [Managing Jobs Across an Enterprise](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187091.aspx)
- [Automating Administration Across an Enterprise](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180992.aspx)

You should also look into Centralised Managed Servers in SSMS:

- [Administering Multiple Servers Using Central Management Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895144.aspx)
- [Application and Multi-Server Management](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee364757.aspx) (SQL 2008 R2 only)

Answer (score 2):

You can only access an external server if it is a linked server in the server that you are running the query from. After adding the server as a linked server access objects on that server with the full name -- [servername].[database].[dbo].[object].

Answer (score 1):

You can issue queries against [linked servers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) with the `OPENQUERY` function. See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx).

If you'd rather do it without a linked server, with an ad-hoc connection (specifying the connect string in the function call), use `OPENROWSET`. See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx).